# How to get information from a Java Process?

Tags: java, process, instance

So, say I have multiple instances of a java program running, and I need to get information from each instance, ie if the program is performing its function correctly and if its not I need to get information to the process on what to do, I essentially need to open a tunnel. How would I do so? I hope this question isn't to vague.

I'm basically writing a manager, the manager loads a bunch of clients and I need a way to communicate between the manager and each client.

Comment: Information as in how much proccessor is each program running, how much memory, and the state?

Comment: @JClassic more the stage of the program, what's executing, logs, etc... I'm hoping I don't have to use injection. And I'm assuming there's no way of using reflection

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Java Management Extensions?  It's built-in and made for monitoring java processes:

http://openjdk.java.net/groups/jmx/

if you need to look at custom info for your processes (some state of execution, or some special log info), you can create your own info-providers (aka "MBeans"):

https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/developing_custom_mbeans_to_ma

hope that helps